# Is it possible to use regex with cucumber.options tags?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want run multiple cucumber feature tags. I don't want to mention all the tags in the command line because it can be tedious if there are lots of tags. Instead I want to provide a pattern of tags that will run all the tags which matches the pattern like -Dcucumber.options=" --tags @my-test*". This will run all the tags that matches @my-test patter.

So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What happened when you tried?

I don't there is a way to do it and I have a hard time to see that you would have so many tags that it would be valuable. If you have that many tags, maybe you have another problem and should cut down on the number of tags used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cucumber ruby, then you can use profiles to do this using `cucumber.yml`. I don't know if there is an equivalent in java. If there isn't I would just create some shell scripts (maybe even aliases) to deal with this.